# JQUERY: find checkboxes in a jQuery SELECTOR by matching on part of a string that is in the OnClick Attribute

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onclick, attributes, selector

We have a JQUERY challenge  in that **we need to find checkboxes in a JQuery SELECTOR  by matching on part of a string that is in the OnClick Attribute.**
If we were matching on a NAME or ID, it would be very easy,  but the checkboxes are created by our application that creates the HTML as follows.

```
  <input type="checkbox"  name="alternate" value="" onClick="moreStudyDetFunctions.setValue(moreStudyDetFunctions.formObj,24242,1)">
```

In the old version of Jquery, we were able to find this
jQuery("input:checkbox[onclick*=,24242]").attr("checked")

The current version of JQuery seems not to support this and requires me to change my code.

I can get the OnClick Attribute as follows:
$('input:checkbox').attr('onClick')

**But I  do not know how to limit the checkbox selector to only match on ‘24242’ found inside the onClick attribute**

The :contains command  does not seem to apply to checkboxes.
This will not work    $('input:checkbox').contains(‘24242’)

Perhaps $('input:checkbox').filter    ?

Comment: All you have to do is quote the attribute-value: `jQuery("input:checkbox[onclick*=',24242']")`, as in the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1kgr6boc/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf`, if doesn't exist it will print -1 else index of the first occurrence

```js
console.log($('input:checkbox').attr('onClick').indexOf('24242'))
//if -1 not found else found

//example
if ($('input:checkbox').attr('onClick').indexOf('24242') > -1) {
  console.log(`found at index ${$('input:checkbox').attr('onClick').indexOf('24242')}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="alternate" value="" onClick="moreStudyDetFunctions.setValue(moreStudyDetFunctions.formObj,24242,1)">
```

Reference:

- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Simone, thank you very much! That is correct, but I'm actually trying to have this result in a selector , and then do something with it like inspect it's checked property or set it. You did put me on the right track!

Here would be my solution resulting in a sector: 

  $('input:checkbox').filter(function() {
                return $('input:checkbox').attr('onClick').indexOf('24242') > 0
            })

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I need to use a .filter,  but since its a string search Ill need an anonomous function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('input:checkbox').filter(function() {
    return $('input:checkbox').attr('onClick').indexOf('24242') > 0
  }).length);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  name="alternate" value="" checked   onClick="moreStudyDetFunctions.setValue(moreStudyDetFunctions.formObj,24242,1)">
```